# Cufon doesnt work iE

Tags: internet-explorer, cufon

I found some topics like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cufon%20ie).

but i couldn't fix the problem. My Cufon replace Js is; This part is in the {PozitifJs.js}

```
Cufon.replace('.topShout', {textShadow: '1px 1px 1px black', fontStyle:'italic'}); 
Cufon.replace('.widgetTitle', {textShadow: '1px 1px 1px white', fontStyle:'italic'}); 
Cufon.replace('.mainMenu', {textShadow: '1px 1px 1px black', fontStyle:'italic', hover: true});
```

My header.php doctype ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Also my Cufon scripts :

```
<script src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>/s/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>/s/myriad-pro.cufonfonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>/s/PozitifJs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What should i do ?
Thanks ;)